# Programming with c#

Tags: c#, ide

I am a beginner for programming with C#. I'm using a windows 7 machine and, I want to know what are the software I need to install in addition to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. What are the other best IDEs' used for programming with C#.

Comment: For a beginner, VS2010 is enough

Comment: `What are the other **best** IDEs' used for programming with C#.` No, just no.

Comment: You are already on Very Good Plat-form. You probably do not need anything else for now. So, dont get your head around, and start Practicing on VS 2010. Best of Luck...

Comment: @HarisHasan: moreover, it's enough for professional. :)

Comment: As a beginner I recommended grabbing the express version of 2012, it's free. The UI is much nicer than 2010 IMO and little additions have made it much nicer to use. Example: clicking on a class/page allows you to view it in the main window but doesn't open it. So i can click through several classes and view them without ending up with 10 tabs open as each one disappears as i move onto the next.

Comment: Thank You All for your valuable answers and for your attention!!!!